# How to dump square brackets in json object without having to do for loops

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am doing some analysis on world cup data, I found scrapped json file of records,

it is a json object that you can check [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openfootball/world-cup.json/master/2018/worldcup.json)

I want to get the name and time of the goal for every match.

The problem I am facing is that the json has square brackets, because of that I have to through doing many for loops.

Can I avoid having to do this?

```
import requests
import json

r = requests.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openfootball/world-cup.json/master/2018/worldcup.json')
results = json.loads(r.text)

for round in results['rounds']:
    for match in round['matches']:
        if match['score1'] != 0 :
            for goal in match['goals1']:
                print(goal['name'])
                print(goal['minute'])
        if match['score2'] != 0:
            for goal in match['goals2']:
                print(goal['name'])
                print(goal['minute'])
```

Comment: Square brackets make arrays, which must be looped over if you want all elements

Comment: What you have looks fine to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have to through doing many for loops.
>   Can I avoid having to do this?

You can't avoid loops completely, but you can hide some of them in generator expressions:

```python
import itertools


def matches():
    m = [round['matches'] for round in results['rounds']]
    yield from itertools.chain(*m)
```

Then you need only one single loop for all the matches:

```python
for match in matches():
    your existing code here...
```

Of course, you can play the iterator game one more level and also have the goals `yield`ed by a generator. This is just an example how it could work.

Please note the your data contains entries which have `score1 > 0` but no key `goals1`. You could consider using a `try` block. Then you don't even to check the score: just try the goals and you are done. So, that boils down to:

```python
for match in matches():
    try:
        for goal in match['goals1']:
            print(goal['name'])
            print(goal['minute'])
    except KeyError:
        pass

    try:
        for goal in match['goals2']:
            print(goal['name'])
            print(goal['minute'])
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work ok. Some of the matches though do not contain `goal` fields which can be fixed by using `.get()` with a default. Yes the loops are needed, it can though be simplified slightly as follows:

```
from operator import itemgetter
import requests
import json

r = requests.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openfootball/world-cup.json/master/2018/worldcup.json')
results = json.loads(r.text)
get_fields = itemgetter('name', 'minute')

for round in results['rounds']:
    for match in round['matches']:
        for goal in match.get('goals1', []) + match.get('goals2', []):
            print(', '.join(map(str, get_fields(goal))))
```

This would give you output starting:

```
Gazinsky, 12
Cheryshev, 43
Dzyuba, 71
Cheryshev, 90
Golovin, 90
```

[`itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html?highlight=itemgetter#operator.itemgetter) is a useful way to extract required fields from a list or dictionary.

Answer (score -1):

May be the answer is not the one looking for,  found schema very intersting in parsing json and validating

Try this https://github.com/keleshev/schema
Create schema for one match.. using schema you could extract relevant data.

```
import requests
import json
from schema import Schema, Use, Or, Optional

r = requests.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openfootball/world-cup.json/master/2018/worldcup.json')
results = json.loads(r.text)

schmeMatch = Schema({
        Optional(Or('goals1','goals2')) : [
            Use(lambda obj: [obj['name'], obj['minute']] )
        ]
    },ignore_extra_keys=True)

for round in results['rounds']:
    for match in round['matches']:
        goals = schmeMatch.validate(match)
        print(goals)
```

Result:

```
{'goals1': [['Gazinsky', 12], ['Cheryshev', 43], ['Dzyuba', 71], ['Cheryshev', 90], ['Golovin', 90]], 'goals2': []}
{'goals1': [], 'goals2': [['Giménez', 89]]}
{'goals1': [['Ronaldo', 4], ['Ronaldo', 44], ['Ronaldo', 88]], 'goals2': [['Costa', 24], ['Costa', 55], ['Nacho', 58]]}
{'goals1': [], 'goals2': [['Bouhaddouz', 90]]}
{'goals1': [['Griezmann', 58], ['Behich', 81]], 'goals2': [['Jedinak', 62]]}
```